# File Browser Dialog MVVM C#, return complete path to view model and diplay only file name in view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a dialog window and I need to return a complete file path to my viewmodel and I would like to do this but show only file name in text box in view for user. I have a behaviors class and a viewmodel and a view. I tried catching the name as a property in the behaviors class but I am not getting the value when I bind to a text box to check for output. Here is the browser dialog

```
namespace BasemapCreator.Behaviors
{
    public class FolderDialogBehavior:Behavior<System.Windows.Controls.Button>
    {

        public void FolderBrowserDialog()
        {


        }
        public string SetterName { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Click += OnClick;
        }
        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {

            AssociatedObject.Click -= OnClick;
        }
        private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK && AssociatedObject.DataContext != null)
            {
                var propertyInfo = AssociatedObject.DataContext.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
                    .First(p => p.Name.Equals(SetterName));

                string dirName = new DirectoryInfo(dialog.SelectedPath).Name;
                FolderName = dirName;
                _fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dirName);
                FileName = _fileName;
                ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Dialogs.MessageBox.Show(FileName.ToString());
                propertyInfo.SetValue(AssociatedObject.DataContext, dialog.SelectedPath, null);
            }
        }
        private string _folderName;
        public string FolderName
        {
            get { return _folderName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _folderName )
                {
                    _folderName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FolderName");
                }
            }

        }
        private string _fileName;
        public string FileName
        {
            get { return _fileName; }
            set
            {
                if (_fileName != value)
                {
                    _fileName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
                }
            }

        }
        private string _styleName;
        public string StyleName
        {
            get { return _styleName; }
            set
            {
                if (_styleName != value)
                {
                    _styleName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("StyleName");
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, args);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Binding in the View

```
<TextBox x:Name="gdbName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="56,29,0,0"  Text="{Binding FolderName, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282" AllowDrop="True">
        </TextBox>
```

And in the ViewModel I have the FolderName property

```
private string _folderName;
public string FolderName
{
   get { return _folderName; }
   set
      {
        _folderName = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("FolderName");
      }
}
```

everything works but the pathnames are so long that sometimes they are hidden. I would like to show file name and pass complete path.

Comment: Why don't you just create a new object that contains whatever you need ? In this case a file name and the complete path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible or at least very complicated if you display a shortened path or filename but let the user enter a full path…

I would use two different fields or use a `OneWay` `Binding` and let the user only select a new file with the `FileOpenDialog` but not let him enter a path manually…

So you create another property in your view model like:

```
public string SortenedFolderName => Path.GetFileName(_folderName);

private string _folderName;
public string FolderName
{
   get { return _folderName; }
   set
   {
        _folderName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FolderName));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SortenedFolderName));
    }
}
```

and bind to this property like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SortenedFolderName, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Works perfectly